# What's the difference between using self.attribute and attribute in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between using self.attribute and attribute in a model?

In this example, assume my_attr is an attribute of the user that gets stored in the database.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_something!
    self.my_attr = 123
  end

  def do_another_thing!
    my_attr = 456
  end
end
```

Comment: using `self` just protects you from running into potential name clashes with local variables of same name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The difference in your examples is that the first one works, the second doesn't.

Your second version isn't doing anything (at least nothing meaningful). Writing `my_attr = 123` is *not* equivalent to `self.my_attr = 123`. Instead it's creating a local variable called `my_attr` and setting it to `123`, and then immediately reaching the end of the method and throwing `my_attr` away. The whole method is essentially a [no-op](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/25994), and it doesn't affect the model's `my_attr` value in any way.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_another_thing!
    my_attr = 456
    
    puts self.my_attr # nil (or whatever value it was before)
  end
end
```

Conversely, if you want to *access* a method defined on an object, you can (and [should](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required)) omit `self`:

```
class User
  def name=(value)
    @name = value
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def age=(value)
    @age = value
  end

  def age
    @age
  end

  def do_something
    self.name = "bob" # self is required
    puts name # bob (self.name)

    age = 47 # @age is unaffected
    age # 47 (local variable), but self.age is nil 
    
  end
end
```

Note that, this isn't a Rails question, it's a Ruby question. There is no Rails-specific code here, this behaviour is part of how Ruby's syntax works.

Comment: OK, thanks. Why do you recommend NOT using self.name when you want to get name, but using self.name when you want to set name?  I would think you'd want to use self.name in both cases, for consistency.

Comment: @SomeGuy Because it's the [agreed upon standard](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required)

Comment: @SomeGuy Just because it's a Rubocop rule doesn't mean it makes sense for you, your team or your project. You can easily disable it or sometimes enforce the opposite, if that makes more sense to you. We do that on a few Rules that don't jive with how we read and write our Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

the general rule is, whenever you are modifying self by assigning value to some attribute, use 'self' explicitly

```
self.first_name = 'Prasad' #if self isnt used, it will create a local variable.
```

and if you are referencing that attribute(but not modifying), dont use 'self'

```
def name
  name.camelize
end
```

----UPDATE-----

whenever we access any attribute, ruby will check if getter (reader) and setter (writer) methods for that attribute are defined or not.

So in the above case(when you are assigning a value to attribute), you arent accessing the attribute directly but passing value to the setter which will internally assign the value to the attribute.

```
2.1.0p0 :008 > User.first.first_name
=> "Prasad" 
2.1.0p0 :009 > (User.first.methods - Object.methods).include? :first_name
=> true 
2.1.0p0 :010 > (User.first.methods - Object.methods).include? :first_name=
=> true
```

You can try it by adding a method to the any model

```
def some_name
  first_name = 'Some name'
  puts self.first_name
  self.first_name = 'Random Username'
  puts self.first_name
end
```

and reload the console and do

```
2.1.0p0 :017 > User.first.some_name
Prasad
Random Username
=> nil
```

Comment: @muistooshort added details to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is no difference. But assume that you have a local variable in a method definition:

```
def do_something!
  self.my_attr = 123
end

def do_another_thing!(my_attr)
  puts "my_attr is #{my_attr}"
  puts "self.my_attr is #{self.my_attr}"
end

do_something!          
do_another_thing!(456)
```

Then the output would be

```
my_attr is 456
self.my_attr is 123
```

`self` represents an object. When you call method on `self` you call method specifically on that object.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword self in Ruby gives you access to the current object – the object that is receiving the current message.

So `self.attribute` refers to `current object's attribute`, where as simply `attribute` is there with its `scope`.

Read this guide [self](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby) for more detailed info.

Answer (score -1):

do_something! is a instance method. So here the self is the User instance, my_attr= is your User instance's method. The function is to assign a value to user instance variable @may_attr.

In "do_another_thing!", my_attr could be a variable you just declared.

Comment: That isn't true. Assuming that the `users` table has a `my_attr` column, the effect of `self.my_attr=...` is *not* to set `@my_attr`.